# Telerik Mega Menu not working with jquery1.7 in IE

Tags: jquery, telerik

I have used an easy slider and a Telerik Mega Menu on my website. The following Script is included for slider along with the reference of the jquery 1.7.1:

Here is the code for my mega menu:

```
@(
 Html.Telerik().Menu()
        .Name("Mega Menu")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "background:#000000;" })
        .OpenOnClick(true)                  
        .Items(menu =>
        {
            menu.Add().Text("Mega Menu:")
                .ContentHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:550px;" })
                .Content(@<text>

                        <ul>
                        <li>Group1
                             <ul>
                               <li>Item1</li>
                               <li>Item2</li>
                               <li>Item3</li>
                               <li>Item4</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul>
                        <li>Group2
                             <ul>
                               <li>Item1</li>
                               <li>Item2</li>
                               <li>Item3</li>
                               <li>Item4</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
 </text>);
        }
        )
        )
```

Using these 2 scripts my slider as well as Mega Menu function properly in Mozilla Firefox and Chrome.
But in IE8 jquery1.7.1 doesn't allow the Mega Menu to work. It works only if i use jquery1.5.1. But with this jquery, my slider stops functioning in other browsers. Although, there is no such problem in the functioning of slider by using jquery1.7.1 in IE8.

Is there any way that i can use jquery 1.7.1 for the Mega Menu to work, without disturbing the functioning of my slider on any of the browsers(Firefox, Chrome, IE7,8 and 9)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the name of the menu. This is not supported. Try removing the space:

```
.Name("MegaMenu")
```